# Finding a bijection to prove the amount of binary strings of length $n$ with $k$ non-consecutive 1s is ${{n - k + 1}\choose{k}}$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm confused as to how to find a bijection to prove the set of binary strings of length $n$ with $k$ non-consecutive 1s is ${{n - k + 1}\choose{k}}$

I understand that if there is a bijection, both sets the are the same size. So it would seem reasonable that I need to find a bijection from this set of binary strings to a set with known size ${{n - k + 1}\choose{k}}$?

Although I do not understand how to come up with such a set or prove there is a bijection between them. Could anyone walk me through this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that there must be a zero between any two adjacent ones in the sequence. You can remove the $0$ immediately to the right of each of the first $k-1$ ones. What does this give you a bijection with? In fact it's the set of arbitrary strings of length $n-k+1$ with $k$ ones. To find the inverse, take your string of length  $n-k+1$ and insert a $0$ immediately to the right of the first $k-1$ ones.